# Visual effect dissolve support desktop in Livecode?

Tags: livecode

I have problem. My problem is visual effect dissolve. I use effect dissolve for transition show/hide image. On device it's working fine. But on desktop it's not working

This simple code :

```
lock screen for visual effect
      hide img nImg of grp "intro"
      show img (nImg+1) of grp "intro"
unlock screen with visual effect dissolve slow
```

Visual effect dissolve support desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try quoting the effect description;

```
lock screen for visual effect
      hide img nImg of grp "intro"
      show img (nImg+1) of grp "intro"
unlock screen with visual effect "dissolve slow"
```

(works for me on version 6.6.2)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I can do it.